# Ionic content split view on ipad

Tags: ipad, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic Framework here, and what I want to do is to display a content with 2 separate content (left side, right side) that are scrollable on both side.

For example, the left side for displaying the article and the right side is for image gallery.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a one row table (use a ion-row with two ion-col) add Ion-list under each column.

```
<ion-row>
        <ion-col width-50>
            <ion-list>
               <ion-item *ngFor="let article of articles">
                    <h2>{{article.title}}</h2>                         
               </ion-item>
            </ion-list> 
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-50>
               <ion-item>
                    *display your image here*
               </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Hope this helps